# ip address range of google notification servers google-cloud-storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have setup google object notification for buckets in google-storage, our network administrator wants to restrict incoming ip address and wants it to be only google specific.

Is there a range of IP address that are used by google for posting object notification request?

Answer (score 1):

There are no guarantees about what IP addresses the notifications will come from.

Instead, when you initially create the notification channel, set a custom client token. When notifications are delivered, they will include the custom token. Your servers can verify the token before processing the incoming messages.

Comment: is there any guarantee that they will come from an origin within the same project as the service account that set up the channel?

Comment: for example if my application server has firewalls around it, but is accessible from within its project, if these notifications come from outside the project then the application is not accessible